# Django Filter Results

Tags: python, django, filter

I am a little stuck on how to perform a task, so was wondering if anyone could help.

I have this model and model form:

```
class Prefabrication(models.Model):
    prefabrication_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    matlist = models.ForeignKey(MatList, blank=True, null=True)
    sizelist = models.ForeignKey(SizeList, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    workpack = models.ForeignKey(Workpack, blank=True, null=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lineclass = models.ForeignKey(Lineclass, blank=True, null=True)


class CreateNewPrefabForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Prefabrication
        fields = ('prefabrication_id', 'matlist', 'sizelist', 
                  'quantity', 'workpack', 'lineclass')
```

This represents a form i am using to collect information from the user.

I am trying to get a certain value from the lookup table based on the matlist, and sizelist
values given by the user.

I have tried using this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if createprefabcons['newprefab'].is_valid():
        item = Lineclass.objects.filter(itemname__icontains=createprefabcons['newprefab'].cleaned_data['matlist'],
                                        dn1__icontains=createprefabcons['newprefab'].cleaned_data['sizelist'],
                                        lineclassname__icontains=createprefabcons['newprefab'].cleaned_data['matlist'])
        createprefabcons['newprefab'].cleaned_data['code'] = item
        createprefabcons['newprefab'].save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

with filters to try and get the code of the item returned by filtering. As far as i know there
should only be one item returned from the filter search and that item will have a code that i wish to add after the user has given the details to search by.

Everything saves fine into the db but the code field is blank so either i am doing something wrong or there is no value that matches, which if the filtering is done right their has to be a match. Could anyone please give some advice.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter()` returns a [QuerySet()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet) which is *list-like* and full of model objects.  So even if there is only one result, you may need to pull it out of the returned list.

```
item = Lineclass.objects.filter()[0]
```

You may be better off using [`.get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) if you expect there to be only one entry, this will also check your assumption, since it will throw an exception if more than one entry is returned.  Maybe something like this:

```
try:
    item = Lineclass.objects.get(itemname__icontains=createprefabcons['newprefab'].cleaned_data['matlist'], dn1__icontains=createprefabcons['newprefab'].cleaned_data['sizelist'], lineclassname__icontains=createprefabcons['newprefab'].cleaned_data['matlist'])
except Lineclass.DoesNotExist:
    # handle case where no items are found
    do_stuff()
createprefabcons['newprefab'].cleaned_data['code'] = item
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! After trying this method, get() returned 2 items, so i tried filter again using item = Lineclass.objects.filter()[0] to see what is was returning, and it seems to be returning only the first column of the table, lineclass_id, which is 11011, but not the whole row. Same thing if i try with Lineclass.objects.filter()[1].